# How to use a `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, dd

Given: a `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` duplicate drive of the main boot drive.

How does one safely, reliably :

1. mount a `dd` duplicate drive as a second drive?
2. setup the `dd` duplicate drive as alternate boot drive?
3. safe practice to restore from a `dd` duplicate drive?

My notes so far on for Ubuntu 12.04 are as follows:

- **Mount.** The Ubuntu Utility `Mount Volume` gives the error `Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with: mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /
  mount failed`.  Is there a safe way to just mount a duplicate boot volume as a second drive?
- **Boot.** Function key to select the start up disk from the BIOS/GRUB appears to be the way to go.  What does it mean if a blank screen is seen after the disk is selected far what seems to be a long time?
- **Restore.**  If the duplicate is used as the /dev/sda boot drive is `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` OK as a restore procedure? Or, is it safer use some third minimal boot (e.g. USB) drive for `sudo dd if=/dev/duplicate of=/dev/toberestored`? or something else?

Background Context:  There is an Ubuntu 12.04 embedded system that I would like to migrate forward with a clean (not-upgrade) install of Ubuntu 14.04.  This is a single board system with and fixed main SSD drive.

Current thinking is to create the following:

1. **File Migration Disk.**  A mountable drive with the 12.04 files which can be seen by the 14.04 system. (alternately possible with `rync`)
2. **Regression Test Dual-Boot Configuration Disks**.  A dual boot drive configuration with an external 12.04 drive or fixed internal SSD (with a clean 14.04 install) can be use to boot the system. (can `dd` be used here?)
3. **Baseline Backup Disk**.  A full image, non-incremental, as-is, if-needed revert to 12.04 recovery drive. (completely separate drive from 1 & 2)

Where could and how would `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` drive process fit into the above migration scenario?

Comment: What do you want to do? The only thing that would change is the UUID(from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb. The black screen might eb a UUID issue

Comment: Are you trying to use dd for backup? You cannot mount both drives as they then are duplicate UUIDs and that is not allowed.

Comment: @wilhelm-erasmus I'm trying to understand where a `dd` image drive fits into a migration from 12.04 to 14.04.  More context has been added to the question.

Comment: @oldfred yes, a backup is one of the goals.  Another goal is to create a dual boot two-drive configuration.

Comment: I might just have two totally separate installs, and use rsync to copy data and maybe some of the configurations. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem and:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery With Linux there are many ways to back up. And dd is probably last on the list.